# how to use sessionStorage instead of localStorage in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to angular and asp.net web api. I am creating website using asp.net web api 
and angular 7 and i done registration and login work but now i need to use sessionStorage instead of localStorage
 in angular code. i am sharing all that files where i use localStorage and localStorage code is working perfectly but now i need to use sessionStorage .it show all the information of user which is login currently .kindly help me. thank you.i share all the code that i have done for localstorage i know it confusing but hope you can solve my problem.i remove import statements from code and html code which done to show login user info like username email and full name.

This is the interceptor class

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router) {

    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
            const clonedReq = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'))
            });
            return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
                tap(
                    succ => { },
                    err => {
                        if (err.status == 401){
                            localStorage.removeItem('token');
                            this.router.navigateByUrl('/user/login');
                        }
                    }))}
        else
            return next.handle(req.clone());
    }}


  //login compnent ts file 
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styles: []
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      formModel ={
        UserName :'',
        Password:''
      }
      constructor(private service: UserService, private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null)
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.login(form.value).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      },
      err => {
        if (err.status == 400)
          this.toastr.error('Incorrect username or password.', 'Authentication failed.');
        else
          console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

//auth.grud.ts file

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null)
      return true;
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['/user/login']);
      return false;
    }

  }
}
```

//home component.ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  userDetails;

  constructor(private router: Router, private service: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUserProfile().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.userDetails = res;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
    );
  }

  onLogout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.router.navigate(['/user/login']);
  }
}
```

kindly tell me how can i do this task.

Comment: why not just replace localStorage with sessionStorage? their APIs are the same

Comment: From what I understand from your question, you want to use sessionStorage instead of localStorage. So, replace it with sessionStorage. Same syntax.
`sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');` `let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key')`;

Comment: @Andrei i do the same process what you saying but i want to show user name just like when we login into google then it show pic or name first word . so how i can do this

Comment: @Sanju i agree but how to show the username in navigation bar...

Comment: Still unclear of what you want to achieve. Once you get value from `public data = sessionStorage.getItem('key')`, show it wherever you want in Html using `{{data}}`